# Struggling with a series of variables

Tags: python, twitter, tinyurl

To avoid tweets becoming caught in the twitter spam filter I have some code that goes to tinyurl and creates a new short url each time the code is run for each of the original urls. What i want is each time `'u'` is printed, it's value should be passed to a variable `'linkvar1', 'linkvar2', 'linkvar3'` etc. This is the passed to the tweet submission later in the code:

```
import simplejson
import httplib2
import twitter
import tinyurl

print("Python will now attempt to submit tweets to twitter...")

try:

    api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='',
                      consumer_secret='',
                      access_token_key='',
                      access_token_secret='')

    for u in tinyurl.create('http://audiotechracy.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/reviewing-synapse-antidote-rack.html',
                        'http://audiotechracy.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/free-guitar-patches-for-propellerhead.html',
                        'http://audiotechracy.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/get-free-propellerhead-rock-and-metal.html',
                        ):
        print u
        linkvar1 = u
        linkvar2 = u
        linkvar3 = u

    status = api.PostUpdate("The new Synapse Antidote Rack Extension:" + linkvar1 + " #propellerhead #synapse")
status = api.PostUpdate("Free Propellerhead guitar patches for everyone!" + linkvar2 + " #propellerhead #reason #guitar")
status = api.PostUpdate("Free Metal and Rock drum samples!" + linkvar3 + " #propellerhead #reason)


print("Tweets submitted successfully!")
```

except Exception,e:
    print str(e)
    print("Twitter submissions have failed!!!")

However at the minute all this does is use the tinyurl generated last for all tweets submitted. I'm sure this is an easy fix that I'm just being stupid about, but does anyone know how to do what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you aren't doing anything with your `linkvar` variables through each loop. Thus, each time the loop runs, they are getting overwritten.

You have a few options

Option 1: Make the `linkvar`s a list that you append to each loop

```
linkvar1 = []
for u in ...
   ...
   linkvar1.append(u)

# Post to twitter
for p in linkvar1:
    status = api.PostUpdate("The new Synapse Antidote Rack Extension:" + p + " #propellerhead #synapse")
    status = api.PostUpdate("Free Propellerhead guitar patches for everyone!" + p + " #propellerhead #reason #guitar")
    status = api.PostUpdate("Free Metal and Rock drum samples!" + p + " #propellerhead #reason)
```

At the end of your first for loop, you will have values in the `linkvar` variable. I am not sure why you are using three, do I chopped it down to just the single instance. You can then loop through using another `for` loop, or passed whole-sale to your own function that will handle them appropriately. In either case, all of your urls are now in a list in each of these variables

Option 2: Call a function to perform on each loop

```
for u in ...
   ...
   MyTwitterFunction(u)

def MyTwitterFunction(url):
    status = api.PostUpdate("The new Synapse Antidote Rack Extension:" + url + " #propellerhead #synapse")
    status = api.PostUpdate("Free Propellerhead guitar patches for everyone!" + url + " #propellerhead #reason #guitar")
    status = api.PostUpdate("Free Metal and Rock drum samples!" + url + " #propellerhead #reason)
```

Each time the loop is iterated over, the `MyTwitterFunction` will be called with the value of `u`.

Option 3: Pull your posting code directly into your `for` loop

```
for u in ...
    status = api.PostUpdate("The new Synapse Antidote Rack Extension:" + u + " #propellerhead #synapse")
    status = api.PostUpdate("Free Propellerhead guitar patches for everyone!" + u + " #propellerhead #reason #guitar")
    status = api.PostUpdate("Free Metal and Rock drum samples!" + u + " #propellerhead #reason)
```

This eliminates the need for the `linkvar` variables and the extra `for` loop. You can post directly from the loop in which the URLs are created.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you mean by "passed to a variable". It looks as though you're assigning the value of u to each of your 3 variables and then over-writing it - e.g.:

```
 for x in range(5):
   y = x
```

Will result in the value of 4 being assigned to y. Did you maybe want to make a list? For example:

```
y = []
for x in range(5):
  y.append(x)
```

which will result in

```
y = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

I think this is what you're aiming for with your link1,2,3 variables.

Comment: Basically im creating 21 shortened URLs to be used in 21 tweets...each tweet needs a different link in it. If i create a list in the above fashion how to i then pass each of the list's values in turn to the different tweets?

Comment: @user3045351 At a later point in your code, you could loop over the lists and pass their elements wherever you need to pass them. Or, as Andy points out (and I wish I had), you could also just call whatever function you need to call from within the main loop you've already made.

Comment: i'm a little confused by how to apply your answer to my scenario so i have amended my answer to show my full code but simplified to just three url's.

Comment: @ser3045351 - indenting your "status =" lines so that they fall within the for loop.